# Truncamento de valores em R

Tags: r

Preciso fazer uma pesquisa para detectar quantos funcionários atualmente ganham igual ou acima do teto INSS (R$ 5531.31, no mês referência da base). As bases que possuo informam os valores de contribuição do servidor(11%) e do patronal(22%), mas não a remuneração total. Por tanto um funcionário que ganhe mais ou igual ao tato ele contribuem com o mesmo valor, pois o máximo da base de cálculo é o referido teto. O problema é que `0.22 * 5531.31 = 1216.888`, mas as bases que possuo simplemente ignoram o último número. Um funcionário que ganhe mais ou igual ao teto tem como contribuição `R$ 1216.88` e o R não consegue detectar quem ganha a mais (ou igual), pois ele arredonda o resultado da multiplicação para `1216.89`. Há alguma função que faça ignorar os últimos digitos sem que ele faça o arredondamento?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não conheço nenhuma função nativa do R que faça isto, mas eu criei rapidinho uma função que acredito que faça o que tu deseja:

```
arredondamento <- function(x){
  floor(100*x)/100
}
```

Utilizei o teu exemplo nela e deu o resultado esperado:

```
> arredondamento(0.22 * 5531.31)
[1] 1216.88
```

Esta função pode, inclusive, ser aplicada em vetores:

```
valores <- c(12.567, 31.333, 0.771)
arredondamento(valores)
[1] 12.56 31.33  0.77
```

Comment: Muito bom, solução bem simples no estilo: "Pq não pensei nisso antes?!"